# Multiple login forms not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Laravel 6. PHP 7.4.

I'm building a website. As Laravel offers default Auth Login and Registration forms. I put the login form into my navigation while the registration form on Registration page. Now I want to let users offer another login form onto Registration Page.

I designed another login form and on Submit I referred it to the same login route but it's not working. Error is 419 page Expired.

I also read about MutiAuth but that is something I'm going to use for my admin panel. Is there any solution?

Registration.blade

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}"  onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('agreed').checked) { return true; } else { alert('Please indicate that you have read and agree to the privacy policy and terms of use'); return false; }">
                                              
<div class="input-group form-group">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
 </div>

 <input type="email" required name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email address">

  </div>
    <div class="input-group form-group">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
             <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
   </div>
        <input type="password" required name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agreed" />
            <small>I agree to the privacy policy and terms of use</small>
      </div>
       
      <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Route

```
Route::get('login', [
  'as' => 'login',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm'
]);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors ?

Comment: @Saromase
On submit, it redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login and  Error is 419 Page Expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `@csrf` inside your `<form>`.

Comment: OOps. My bad. Token was missing. It's fixed. great ..........

Comment: No problem! I sometimes miss the smallest things too ;)

Comment: I want to override the message "Credentials don't match with our records". 
I want to insert button link for register page. 

I tried to override the line in auth.php but html code for my button is not working. 
Any suggestion?